# Typescript interface properties are changed to Pascal Case from camel Case

Tags: angularjs, typescript, rxjs

I am using Angular 1.4 with type script, and RXJS in an ASP.NET 5 application. I am having extremly wiered issue. During the runtime, all my interface properties are being turned to Pascal Casing from camel casing. Why is this happeing and how to avoid this ?

Please note i am using promises to get data from web api making call like this

```
public GetDataFromAPI(request: Messages.IRequest): Observable<Messages.IResponse> {
    let result: IPromise<Messages.IResponse>;
    result = this.$http.post("http://api.domain.com/GetData", request).then(
        (response: ng.IHttpPromiseCallbackArg<Messages.IResponse>) => {
            return response.data;
        }
    ); 
 return Observable.fromPromise(result).retry(3);
}
```

Here is how i have defined the interface

```
export interface IResponse{

     firstName : string;
     lastName : string;
     age : number


}
```

When i get the the data back, its properties are having CamelCasing like this making them in accessible.

```
response.data.FirstName
response.data.LastName
response.data.Age
```

Comment: The backend must return objects with fields with this case. Check what you get in the network tab of your dev tools.

Comment: It is returning an object with fields, but all field names are Camel Cased, whcih means if i try to access data.firstName anywhere in the code it will be undefined but if i write data.FirstName it works ( i dont want to do that since typescript comiler will throw an error in this case)

Comment: Well, if your backend returns objects with a field named FirstName, nothing will magically transform the field into firstName. Adopt a convention, and stick to it, in the backend and in the frontend.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most probably the server uses PascalCasing, and you defined an interface which does not match the data returned by a server. TypeScript will not convert member names from PascalCase to camelCase, you have to write your own logic. It will not throw an error at runtime either, because interfaces get erased. I suggest you to break the naming convention in the TypeScript part, use PascalCase fields, so the interfaces will match the data transfer objects exactly. So define the interface like this:

```
export interface IResponse {
    FirstName : string;
    LastName : string;
    Age : number;
}
```

And access the field names like `data.FirstName`

Another way to go is to change the server implementation, as Cleverguy25 suggests.

Comment: You can of course make this change, but other javascript programmers will wonder why you broke convention :-(

Comment: @Cleverguy25 It is always a hard decision to make. In some cases you will be not even allowed to change the server code, so you get stuck with this. In other cases it's just a matter of taste.

Answer (score 3):

If your backend is WebApi, by default the normal Json serialization leaves the fields as they are in you c# or vb.net casing.

Look at this article to configure the formatter to return camel casing.

http://richarddingwall.name/2012/03/10/returning-camelcase-json-from-asp-net-web-api/

Answer (score 3):

Here is what needs to be configured

```
HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().First();
jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
```